# Shuffling multiple arrayList in the same order?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, arraylist, shuffle

Hi i have 3 arrayList called trackNum, name and duration. 
The content of the arraylist are connected i.e. Index 1 for trackNum name and duration are linked.

So i created a third array list that i populated with numbers that would get shuffled. The numbers would then be used as an index for the system output.

I need to shuffle the list so the content of each array list are still connected. This is what i have tried.

```
public void shuffleTracks(String tracks){           
    for(int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++){
        numbers.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(numbers); 
    Iterator<Integer> itr = numbers.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(itr.next());
    }

    for(int a = 0; a < name.size(); a++){
        System.out.println(trackNum[numbers[a]] ": " + name[numbers[a]] " " + duration[numbers[a]]);
    }
}
```

I'm getting all my errors on the last system print line, the error says

[image]

Any help would be greatful.

Comment: You could create a class with all needed info and then shuffle a single array list with instances of that class.

Comment: @Jordão Yes, make an answer and show him a simple `Track` class.

Comment: Instead of using an array for each field, it would make more sense to have a class which has each of the fields, and array/collection of this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct answer would be to use [`get(int index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int)) instead of the array access using the brackets (`[index]`) for collections such as lists.

So that would be:

```
numbers.get(a)
```

instead of:

```
numbers[a]
```

Java does not have *syntactic sugar* to replace the `get` method with brackets for array access.

Comment: You are also missing a `+` operator when constructing the string, use `printf` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but im still getting these errors http://imgur.com/15HzYkm, my teacher has asked for arraylists :/

Comment: You should do the same for the other `ArrayList` instances of course, not just for `numbers`...

Comment: Im only getting these errors now "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<Integer>"

Comment: I cannot see how that would be possible from the code that you are giving me. If everything is correct, you should not have any arrays within your code, but it sounds like you have one or two left (maybe as return type?). If you must you can update your code *below* the question you've given us, clearly marked as an edit...